# Can OMS agent for Linux be installed with powershell or via the portal?

Tags: azure, powershell, oms

I need to re-install oms agent for a Linux machine, is there a way to do this via Azure power shell or via the portal?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4131455/how-to-reinstall-operations-management-suite-oms-agent-for-linux) steps

> To remove the existing agent and then install the new agent, follow
>   these steps:
>
> - Connect to the Linux computer, and then open a terminal session. To
>
>   > download the desired script, run the following command:
>
> `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux/master/installer/scripts/onboard_agent.sh`.
>
> - Run `sudo sh onboard_agent.sh --purge`. This downloads the most recent
>     version of the installation script and runs the uninstall ation
>     operation that will remove all existing agent components.
> - Remove the `/etc/opt/microsoft/omsagent and /var/opt/microsoft/omsagent` folders.
> - Run the following command:
>     `sudo sh onboard_agent.sh -w <workspaceid> -s <primarykey>`
>
> **Notes**
>
> - In this command, replace  and  with the
>     appropriate values from the actual Azure workspace ID and primary key,
>     respectively.
> - If you're using a cloud service other than Azure public
>     cloud, you must add the -d parameter that identifies the domain that's
>     to be used. For example, if you use the Azure US Government cloud, run
>     the following command:
>
> `sudo sh onboard_agent.sh -w workspaceid -s primarykey -d opinsights.azure.us`

Comment: This is a link only answer that directly copies text from the link.  Add it as a comment, not an answer.